# Change Bg color

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm quite new to coding and trying to make a tic-tac-toe game with Python.
So far it works fine, but i'm having trouble making the buttons change colors.

I want the buttons to look at `Cells[]` for bg color after `move()`.
Maybe that I started with this all wrong. But now I'm clueless.

I cant find any refresh function that I managed to get to work as I wanted.

```
from tkinter import *


class Board:
    def __init__(self):

        self.root =Tk()
        self.root.minsize(300,300)

        self.cells = ["", "white", "white", "white", 
                          "white", "white", "white",
                          "white", "white", "white"]

        self.count = 0  #keeping count of next color



#Player makes a move:
    def move(self, cell_coice):
        x = cell_coice  

        if self.count == 0:
            if self.cells[x] == "white":
                self.cells[x] = "red"
                print (self.cells)          #remove
                self.count = 1
            else:
                self.count = 1
                print (self.cells)          #remove
        else:
            if self.cells[x] == "white":
                self.cells[x] = "blue"
                print (self.cells)          #remove
                self.count = 0
            else:
                self.coint = 0
                print (self.cells)          #remove




    def buttons(self):

        b1 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[1], command=lambda:self.move(1))
        b1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NSEW)

        b2 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[2], command=lambda:self.move(2))
        b2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=NSEW)

        b3 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[3], command=lambda:self.move(3))
        b3.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=NSEW)

        b4 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[4], command=lambda:self.move(4))
        b4.grid(row=2   , column=1, sticky=NSEW)

        b5 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[5], command=lambda:self.move(5))
        b5.grid(row=2   , column=2, sticky=NSEW)

        b6 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[6], command=lambda:self.move(6))
        b6.grid(row=2   , column=3, sticky=NSEW)

        b7 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[7], command=lambda:self.move(7))
        b7.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=NSEW)

        b8 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[8], command=lambda:self.move(8))
        b8.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=NSEW)

        b9 = Button(self.root, bg=self.cells[9], command=lambda:self.move(9))
        b9.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=NSEW)


        Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 1, weight=1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 1, weight=1)
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 2, weight=1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 2, weight=1)
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 3, weight=1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 3, weight=1)



OpenBoard = Board()
OpenBoard.buttons()
OpenBoard.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the colors of the buttons, you need to have access to the button objects. This means you need to add some code to your `buttons()` method to save the objects as a instance variable:

```
self.btns = [Button(), b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9]
```

Now you can add this to your `move()` method to loop through the values and the colors and set each one:

```
for btn, color in zip(self.btns, self.cells):
    btn.config(bg=color)
```

Note you will have to use a valid color for the dummy color in your list, not `""`.